# Approving and rejecting documents in Kentico 9

Tags: c#, kentico

I am extremely new to Kentico world and i just want to use Kentico to to send mail on creating new document to admin who manage document node and sending mail to document creator after approving or rejection of the document. I search on documentation to find how to do so but i can't figure out how.

I successfully configured email parameters but i don't know how to tell the system when and which one it will going to send the mail.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 things you'll need to configure:

- Email server
- Workflow

Sounds as if you might have already configured the email server but if not you can simply do this:

- Go to Settings>System>Mail
- Enter your SMTP address
- If your SMTP relay requires a username and password, enter those

You can test this by going to the Send email tab now in the same area and see if your address and credentials work.

Next go to the Workflow app.

- Click on the pencil next to the Default workflow
- Click on the Steps tab on the left
- Click the green "New Workflow Step" button
- In the name field enter "Submit For Approval" and ensure the "Allows reject" is checked.
- Click Save
- Click on the Security tab on the left.
- For simplicity sake, only include a single user who can approve or reject by checking the "Include the following users radio button.
- Enter yourself and another user as users in the list (for testing)

This should be all you need to get the basic email setup and basic workflow approval process setup.  If you want a more custom configuration I'd suggest checking out the documentation on [Workflow](https://docs.kentico.com/display/k9/Configuring+workflows)

Comment: Thanks a lot appreciate your support as usual :).

Answer (score 4):

Kentico, by default, is configured to email specific roles when a workflow action happens, depending on which role is configured to "approve" it past the step. Every user in the role(s) will be notified.  For each workflow or workflow step, you can choose which user (the submitter or the approver) gets emailed, or both.

Generally, the following notifications are configured:
- When a document is submitted for approver, the "approver" role is notified. 
- When a document is approved, the "submitter" is notified
- When a document is rejected, the "submitter" is notified

Additionally, you can modify the emails that are sent by updating the template for each notification.

You can find out how to configure these settings in the documentation here:

https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Configuring+workflow+email+notifications

- Bryan

Comment: Just to add - Kentico never sends e-mail to person who is responsible for given action. For example if you are the creator of document and then you reject the document, Kentico will not send you the e-mail. When you will be configuring this, be sure to use different users :-)